# Login Screen concerns

Tags: android

I'm creating a login screen in Android Studio and decided that I was going to use the login activity template. There are no errors shown in the code, but my concerns lie in what the emulator tells me.

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE

```
<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton android:id="@+id/plus_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/plus_sign_out_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" android:weightSum="2">

            <Button android:id="@+id/plus_sign_out_button" style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/plus_sign_out" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/plus_disconnect_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/plus_disconnect" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

            <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button" style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton, you are trying to use the Google Play Services API. Did you add the Google Play Services SDK to your project.

Refer to [adding Google Play Services SDK to your Android Project](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)